# How to add a day to pickadate v3 date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have set up a page that holds 2 pickadates. One for a start date and one for an end date.

I also have a number of checkboxes, labeled:

> 1 Day, 1 Month, 1 Year

Once the user selects a date from the first pickadate. They can either pick a second date from the second pickadate.

**But I wish to offer a second alternative. Where if they check 1 day, the 2nd pickadate will be the result of 1 day + the 1st pickdate. Likewise for the 1 month and 1 year checkbox.**

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

My current HTML is:

```
    <div class="inputdata">
        <label>Timeframe:</label>
        <span>
        <div class="section__block section__block--scoped">
            From:
            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" id="input_from">
            </fieldset>
            To:
            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" id="input_to">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        </span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <span><input id="x_timeframe" type="date" name="date_timeframe"></span>
        <label></label>
        <span id="x_timeframe_checkboxes">
            <input type="radio" name="a_timeframe" id="radio4" value="d" class="css-checkbox"/>
            <label for="radio4" class="css-label">1 Day</label>

            <input type="radio" name="a_timeframe" id="radio5" value="w" class="css-checkbox"  />
            <label for="radio5" class="css-label">1 Week</label>

            <input type="radio" name="a_timeframe" id="radio6" value="m" class="css-checkbox" />
            <label for="radio6" class="css-label">1 Month</label>

            <input type="radio" name="a_timeframe" id="radio8" value="n" class="css-checkbox"  />
            <label for="radio8" class="css-label">None</label>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Just for familiarity, the js includes:

```
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/picker.time.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/demo/scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/pickadate1454.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 Day on #from_picker

```
var from_picker = $('#input_from').pickadate(), to_picker = $('#input_from').pickadate();

from_picker.pickadate('picker').on('set', function (event) {
    if (event.select) {
        to_picker.pickadate('picker').set('select', from_picker.pickadate('picker').get('select').pick + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use only JS to do the trick, by getting the value from you date field and transform in a js Date and the add the Days or Moths.

I always create 7 functions, to work with date in JS: addSeconds, addMinutes, addHours, addDays, addWeeks, addMonths, addYears.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/YHA8x/

How to use:

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.addWeeks(3));
```

This are the functions:

```
        Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
            this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + seconds);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes) {
            this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + minutes);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addHours = function(hours) {
            this.setHours(this.getHours() + hours);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
            this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addWeeks = function(weeks) {
            this.addDays(weeks*7);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMonths = function (months) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + months);
            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addYears = function(years) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear() + years);

            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };
```